# Incluir dados através de um explode Mysql/PHP

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém preciso incluir as matérias dentro dos respectivos campos do dia da semana refente aos horários. Para isso, estou usando 02 métodos que criam a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public function cadastrarHEscolas($idEscolas,$idGrades){
   ...
   $this->comboboxGrade($jmVisualizar->IdHorarios,$idEscolas); 
   ...
}

public function comboboxGrade($idHorarios,$idEscolas){

  $sqlListar = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM pe_materias WHERE IdEscolas = '".$idEscolas."';");

    $listar = "<select name='Materias[]' id='materias' class='form-control'>";
        $listar .= "<option value='Selecione'>Matéria</option>";  
        while($jmListar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlListar)){
              $listar .= "<option value='".$jmListar->Materias."_".$idHorarios."'>".$jmListar->Materias."</option>";
         }  
         $listar .= "</select>";
         return $listar;  
}
```

Até aqui tudo bem, porém para eu armazenar dentro do IdHorarios, incluí no segundo método, no atributo option a seguinte linha:

```
$listar .= "<option value='".$jmListar->Materias."_".$idHorarios."'>".$jmListar->Materias."</option>";
```

O código acima me retorna o Id da tabela Horários e a Matéria, separados pelo underline.

E quando clico em cadastrar, uso o método abaixo para cadastrar no banco de dados:

```
    public function cadastrarGradeMaterias($materias){

   // $materias me retorna portugues_1, matematica_1, fisica_2, etc.

       for($m = 0; $m < count($materias); $m++){ 
           $mat = explode("_",$materias);

        $sqlCadastrar = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE tabela SET Segunda - '', Terca = '', Quarta = '', Quinta = '', Sexta = '', Sabado = '' WHERE IdHorario = ''");
       }
    }
```

Aqui que está o problema. Como eu faria para dar um explode e incluir dentro da query os campos selecionados e seu respectivo ID?

Comment: Como você pretende cadastrar os dias se não está postando valores associativos entre dia , matéria e horário? Você só está enviando matéria e horário.E na realidade teria que enviar a matéria  o horario e o dia da semana para efetuar esse update.

Comment: Olá Rafael. Os horários já estão cadastrados, quero apenas fazer o update na tabela incluindo as matérias que estão indo no primeiro bloco de código junto com o Id da tabela. Ex.: portugues_1, matematica_1, etc.

Comment: Nesse caso quando você efetua seu explode pelo underline em $mat[0] está a matéria e $mat[1] o idHorario

Comment: isso... só que conforme a segunda imagem, tem vários campos referentes aos horários. É aí que estou com dificuldades. Como faço para alterar a tabela, incluindo as matérias, nos respectivos campos do dia da semana e horário?

Comment: Era isso que minha primeira mensagem se referiu... Talvez não tenha entendido o que eu disse. Na realidade eu faria essa option atribuindo o atributo name como MateriasSegunda[] , MateriasTerca[] e assim por diante porque quando postar o valor você vai saber o dia a matéria e o idHorario

Comment: Entendi... vou tentar aqui...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem mais um detalhe repare só definiu isso assim :

```
       <select name='Materias[]' id='materias' class='form-control'>
```

eu pedi para renomear, para ter também o entendimento do dia lá na rotina de update. Mas se está definindo um tipo lista no seu html, `name=MateriasSegunda[]` lá no seu código php vai receber um array de valores dos select que tem esse nome no caso seguindo pela sua imagem os valores do select 07:00 - 07:40 , 08:00 - 08:40 e 09:00 - 09-40 portanto esse linha de explode não vai funcionar:

```
  $materias_segunda = $_POST['MateriasSegunda'];
  $mat = explode("_",$materias_segunda);
```

Teria que executar o explode assim:

```
  $materias_segunda = $_POST['MateriasSegunda'];
  foreach($materias_segunda as $materia_hora){
     $mat = explode("_",$materia_hora); 
     $materia_segunda[]        = $materia_hora[0]; 
     $materia_segunda_idHora[] = $materia_hora[1]; 
  }
```

Ou seja o `$_POST['MateriasSegunda']` é uma array contendo as matérias e idHorario na segunda feira.

Depois de efetuar isso em todos os dias da semana, e em posse dos valores do dia hora e matéria ai poderia efetuar seu update.

Melhore meu exemplo escrevi rapidamente apenas para entendimento.

Comment: Olá Rafael. Certo. Vou tentar fazer dessa forma.